# Can't see the billing info of my IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, account, amazon-iam, user-accounts

I created an IAM user for myself and with that account I used EC2 instances. When I login to the main account, I can see that the cost has been billed (available credits reduced) but there is no detailed billing information for the activities under my IAM user account.

I searched online, found consolidated billing option, and sent a consolidated billing request to myself, but error occurred when accepting the request. Don't know what to do now. How can I fix this problem?

P.S. When I create the IAM user, I didn't specify a different email (not required). Maybe that is why AWS is confused and messed up?

Comment: Billing isn't separated by IAM user. AWS isn't "confused and messed up". You are simply looking for a feature that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit confusing in AWS because there's two steps in getting your IAM account to access billing information. First is of course to create an account that has IAM permissions to access billing. 
Second is to login to the root account, go to My Account and scroll to 'IAM User and Role Access to Billing Information'. Click 'edit' and enable 'Activate IAM Access'. You can now view billing information from non-root users with the right permissions.

[image: AWS > My Account]